Help understanding lines 7 & 8 from Shakespeare's 18th sonnet

And every faire from faire some-time declines,


By chance, or natures changing course vntrimm'd,

I have a little difficulty fully understanding these 2 lines.
What does 'faire from faire' mean? Does it mean 'beauty descended from beauty'?
And does the 'some-time' used here mean 'sometimes'(repeatedly) or 'sometime'(once)?
And then in the next line, how does the 'vntrimm'd'(usually spelled 'untrimm'd) function in the sentence? I find the grammar confusing to follow

The original (1608) spelling is "vntrim'd"!

Using modern spelling (I don't think there's any real reason to use Renaissance spelling unless the pronunciation has changed), these lines are:

And every fair from fair sometime declines,
By chance, or nature's changing course untrimmed;

Here fair essentially means beauty, and declines means lessens or decays. More specifically, the first fair means something beautiful, and from fair sometime declines means that sometimes its beauty lessens.
Further, untrimmed had a different meaning when Shakespeare wrote. The OED defines it as "not carefully or neatly arranged or attired," which corresponds to the modern meaning of the word disheveled. (The poem seems to require a meaning somewhat stronger than the OED definition, but this could be attributed to poetic license. )
Finally, you could read sometime here either as repeatedly, or eventually, at some point.
I can't say which meaning Shakespeare intended (in my opinion, it's quite likely he intended both). Comparing it with the line Sometime too hot the eye of heaven shines points to the repeatedly reading, but the general tone of Shakespeare's sonnets (many of which deal with aging and death) points to the once reading.
So, taking the repeatedly reading of sometime, these lines mean something like

every beautiful thing will sometimes lessen from its full beauty,
becoming disheveled, either by chance or by the vagaries of nature.

Note that the line

By chance, or nature's changing course untrimmed,

has resonance with the earlier line

Rough winds do shake the darling buds of May,

rough winds can cause flowers to lose their petals, and become "untrimmed".

Speaking of resonance, I read a piece ages ago (haven't been able to find it since) which suggested that much of Shakespeare's verse should be looked at as couplets with matching or related rhythms.  Many lines would stress the second and fifth beat, feed, but "And EV-'ry FAIR from fair sometimes declines; by CHANCE or NA-ture's changing course untrimmed".  I don't want to claim that interpretation as my own, but alas I can't find the page to cite it properly.

I mentioned this in my own answer, but I'm pretty sure "nature's changing course, untrimmed" is meant to evoke trimming (adjusting) the sails of a ship to keep it on course, not trimming the leaves of a plant.

@JoeSlater: I don't think that Shakespeare was talking about the leaves of a plant. In Shakespeare's time, the word untrimmed meant unadorned, messy, disheveled, or disarranged, and looking at Google books, it often was applied to disheveled clothing. This meaning is now obsolete.

@JoeSlater: In fact, under the entry for the verb untrim, the OED has
"1609–
transitive. To deprive of trimness or elegance; to strip of ornament," and they cite the line:
Euery faire from faire some-time declines, By chance, or natures changing course vntrim'd,
W. Shakespeare. So they claim that here, vntrim'd is a verb, and that Shakespeare was the first person to use it as a verb. (I actually don't see why this usage couldn't be classified as an adjective instead.)

@PeterShor: I think the coinage was the verb "to untrim", as distinct from using "un-" with an adjective to indicate something that isn't ___, or with a past participle to indicate that something hasn't been ___ed.

@PeterShor: As to whether Shakespeare is trying to say "every fair declines, untrimmed by chance or natures changing course", or "every fair declines, by chance or by nature's untrimmed changing course", I would think either interpretation could make sense, though the meaning of "untrimmed" would be different.  I would think the former meaning should have a pause after both "chance" and "course", but since line 7 has no pauses within the last three feet, I would think line 8 should likewise have no pauses there.

@supercat: Yes, that's what the OED seems to say.

@PeterShor "Untrim" may be obsolete, but we still speak of people looking trim. There's also hair, of course, which in "nature's course" needs trimming. ISTM one can justify multiple levels of wordplay.

@PeterShor: Do you think line 8 means "untrimmed by chance or nature's changing course"?  If Shakespeare meant that, this may be the first usage of "to untrim", but applying the meter "by CHANCE, or nature's changing course, unTRIMMED" to line 7 would yield "and EVery fair from fair sometimes, deCLINES".  I think it more natural to pair "and EVery FAIR, from fair sometimes deCLINES" with "by CHANCE or NAture's changing course unTRIM'd".

That's what I think line 8 means. And further, I don't see why the stresses "By CHANCE or NAture's changing course unTRIMMED" aren't consistent with both meanings.

"Sometime" definitely means "sooner or later" in this instance: not that one occasionally gets a little less fair, but that youth is fleeting, beauty has a term, etc.

@LukeSawczak: So you are claiming that the second meaning of sometime definitely has a different meaning than its use in Sometime too hot the eye of heaven shines? I'm not convinced; I think it quite likely that Shakespeare was aware of both possible meanings, and that he intended this line to be polysemic.

@LukeSawczak: But you're right, in that the last six lines tend to force a reinterpretation of this line to make sometime mean sooner or later.

@PeterShor Yes, especially with the reference to an eternal summer that doesn't fade and thus robs death of its boast. I think the declining is certainly the once and final one. The "beauty fades" chivalric poetry trope was still around not too long before Shakespeare (e.g. https://www.bonjourpoesie.fr/lesgrandsclassiques/poemes/pierre_de_ronsard/mignonne_allons_voir_si_la_rose).

That it requires that the same word be used twice with different senses in one poem doesn't seem to me much of an objection; that's not uncommon in poetry, and certainly not foreign to Shakespeare's style of wordplay. (And if it really comes down to it, we could point to this hyphen that the author or editor inserted only in the second "some-time", perhaps to differentiate them...!)

To begin with, Shakespeare (and English generally) often uses adjectives as nouns. The adjective "sweet", for example, can be used to refer to things that are sweet. The same applies to "fair": when the witches in Macbeth say "fair is foul and foul is fair" they mean fair things are foul and foul things are fair. So "every fair" in my opinion should be read as "every fair [thing]". This sonnet is addressed to the temporary nature of things that are fair, which I take to be his subject's fortune (wealth, position) and appearance.
As for the adjective "fair" itself, it is commonly applied to both weather ("a fair day", or "a fair wind") and a person's prospects, and their appearance taken either as a whole ("thou art fair, my love") or by components ("fair hair", or "a fair complexion"). Shakespeare plays with these meanings: a fair day sometimes becomes less fair because of rough winds or excessive heat or clouds; a ship sailing before a fair wind may find that it weakens or changes direction — upon which the captain must have the sails adjusted, or trimmed.
Shakespeare starts by saying that these analogies are weak because his subject is "more lovely and temperate". He concludes by saying that because of his poetry his subject's "eternal summer will not fade" — as all natural things fade — "nor lose possession of that fair thou ow'st" — their memory will not be lost to chance or nature, as actual fair things are.  His subject will be forever preserved in people's minds as they are now.

I agree about using the adjective as a noun and how you're reading "every fair", but I think the lines from Macbeth function differently. I don't think the witches are saying "fair things are foul", but rather that the very concepts of "fair" and "foul" have been reversed – more like "fairness is foulness".
